# Different many-to-many relationships between 2 entities in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I need some advice on designing my Core Data Model.

I have 2 entities, `Person` and `Town`, which I need to link with a "labeled relationship": who can go to which town and how long does it take.

The constraints are:

- the time it takes a person to go to a town cannot be deduced from any other data;
- for a given person, either a town is not accessible or it takes 1 or 2 or ... or 11 hours to go there;
- there are 6000 towns and no town will ever be constructed/destructed;
- there are initially 200,000 persons and that number will grow by 10~100 per day;
- each person can go to 5~1,000 towns (in average, something like 100)

I spent quite some time researching for the best way to model that, and so far I've found 3 ways:

- **Option 1:** creating 11 many-to-many relationships (`r1`, `r2`, ... `r11`). `personA.r3` is the set of `Town`s which `personA` can reach in exactly 3 hours; and `townB.r6` is the set of `Person`s who can go to `townB` in exactly 6 hours.
- **Option 2:** creating an intermediate table (`DurationInfo`)
- **Option 3:** adding a `duration` attribute in the `Town` entity, each town being represented by 11 `Town` objects (one for every possible duration)

### [Graph representations of the 3 options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FTGg.png)

*According to me*, here are the pros and cons:

- option 1 has initially exactly 206,000 objects, it's the most compact (it's the only one I actually tried, and the sqlite files reach 100 MB and I'm not really willing to go far more than that...)
- option 1 seems messy: I read that many-to-many relationships are not really recommended in Core Data, so having 11 of them...
- option 2 seems to be the recommended solution for "labeled relationships", but in my case there are 20,000,000 `DurationInfo` objects (and that will grow by 1,000~10,000 per day), how much space does that take?
- option 3 "only" creates 60,000 more objects, but I don't really like to have that many duplicated data.

So my questions are:

1. Is there one (or more) other option I overlooked?
2. Which option is optimal in my case and why? Which should be my main concern when deciding which way to go?
3. Which option is optimal if some time in the future I need to slightly modify my model?

Thanks a lot in advance for your insights!

Comment: I'm curious how people will answer this. Hands-down I'd do option #2 with an intermediate table unless you have a clear reason to believe it won't be performant. It's far more manageable and as Knuth says, "premature optimization is the root of all evil" as it's often misguided compared to what actually affects performance. SQL in general does very well at this sort of scalability.

Comment: Thanks, RobP, that's actually the kind of answers I'm looking for. I know premature optimisation is the root of all evil, but you wouldn't recommend using strings to store the age of a person, right? I'm very new to Core Data so I may not see obvious downsides of any options, or I may even have missed a more elegant way of dealing with my problem; anyway I'm only asking for educated opinions about designing my model.

Comment: It would help to know how you plan on using the data once you have it. What kinds of lookups do you need to do?

Comment: Tom, you're right, I totally forgot that part. The primary use is very basic: when the user select a person from a table view, a map is displayed with a custom pin (a different one for every "duration") on any town that person can reach; that will always be for a single `Person` object. A second use will most likely be to fetch the persons who can go to a set of towns. And... that's it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information provided, your option 2 is definitely the way to go. The other two options do not scale and are not flexible in case something should change.

As a rule of thumb, if you do not need to persist any information about *the relationship itself* you can go with a simple many-to-many relationship. If you need this info, as is clear in your case, you use this kind of "join" table.

While you got the relationship exactly right, let me suggest different names that will make your code much more readable IMO:

```
Person (trips) <----->> (person) Trip (town) <<-------> (trips) Town
```

Comment: Mundi, thanks for your answer. Since it appears to be the consensus, I'm giving it a try. My main fear about that option was disk space, but it doesn't look to be *that* bad (about +25% compared to option #1).

Also, thanks a lot for you naming suggestion. I knew my naming was off but couldn't figure a more appropriate one. Although, if I'm not mistaken, in the `Trip` entity, the relationships should be singular (`person` and `town`).

Comment: True, the plurals are inappropriate. Corrected.